# Remove querystring from response Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, response

I'm working on a project where after successful Google OAuth Authentication i need to send response to user which contains data in json which works fine.
But the url in the browser contains querystring like this: [image]

I want url in browser till /callback like BASE_URL/auth/google/callback.
This is my code:
[image]

I can i configure it by my node application?

Comment: what you mean by remove?, its needed

Comment: If you want to remove query params, you need to pass this data as JSON in the response and need to update the URL.

Comment: yes i'm already passing required data as JSON in response, i only need a way to update url so user can only see "base_url/auth/google/callback". Is it possible?